# Can't install Intel HAXM. Tried everything I can

Tags: android-studio, haxm

So, I am trying to work on Android Studio. But I can't install Intel HAXM.

I am running Windows 7 and latest android studio

I tried installing from SDK. It installs perfectly but, then "HAXM device not found".
I tried installing different versions of HAXM manually. But everytime these errors pop up, when I do it manually. The errors:

1. [error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fw3RG.png)
2. [error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXgIo.png)
3. [error3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAYWd.png)
4. [error4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SF4bF.png)
5. [error5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5h70B.png)

Things I've tried includes:

1. Enabling Vt-X in advanced BIOS options
2. Disabling Hyper-V
3. Installing update of windows suggested in another thread. Windows6.1-KB3033929-x64.
4. Tried Driver Signature Enforcement Overrider
5. I can't even remember anymore.

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

What type is your processor? The problem with HAXM is what can installed if you have a processor is not Intel. for this reason some peaple use a emulators like bluestacks o something similar. Good Day!

Comment: Well, I have Intel processor. I installed HAXM finally. However, now, when I try to launch the emulator , emulator doesn't start and says the emulator process was finished with exit code 0

Comment: with that, if your emulator doesnt get recognize, you should be sure if you have installed all about VM of android studio, check de components and try again. Or install a emulator and try with that